# Owl carousel number pagination

Tags: html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

Hey i need to make slider like this. Numbers of sliders will appear on the screen how can i do that?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTE57.png

```
 <div id="home" class="hero-slider owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div style="background-image: url(images/slider.png);" class="single-hs-item">
        <div class="container ">
            <div class="d-table cizgi">
                <div class="d-tablecell">
                    <div class="hero-text">
                        <h1>Some Text</h1>
                        <p>Sub Text</p>
                        <div class="slider-btn ">
                            <a href="#" class="custom-btn1">See More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Numbers of sliders will appear on the screen"? Like, when you're on slide 1 it will appear 1 only and so on? It already have circles below presenting number of slides

Comment: I mean like navigation circles numbers will be written according to how many sliders there are

Comment: Like [this](https://i.imgur.com/9HZxUfp.jpg)?